# How to change cell color based on value in web excel

Tags: excel

I'm using Web Excel in a browser.  Can I change color of a cell based on a value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Conditional Formatting" - if you're using Office 365's (2013) web based Excel.  See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx

Comment: I'm not using Office 365 so I don't see "conditional formatting" on the Home tab.

Comment: Are you using this app http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/introduction-to-excel-web-app-HA010378338.aspx ?  This is the only web app for excel that I'm aware of, and It's a part of the office 365 / 2013 suite of web applications.